# Does sentence(s) with semicolon count for one sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am just wondering if I merge two sentences using a semicolon, then are they become one sentence or they are still two sentences but more closely connected?

For example, is the following sentence(s) count for one sentence?

> He knows how important attending lectures is; however, he still missed today's lecture.

**Edit**

As some comments pointed out, the question seems kind of pointless without any context.

I am doing my logic course homework, which requires me to translate English into logical expression. We usually count each sentence as one premise or conclusion. I encountered one problem containing a semicolon so I am not sure whether I should divide them into two premises or just leave it as one.

I guess it's better to ask my professor.

Comment: As to your actual question, the answer depends on your definition of a sentence. Of which there are dozens. And you can easily come up with a dozen more. If you define a sentence as "anything beginning with a capital letter and ending in a period", then obviously your fragment is one sentence. If you define a sentence as "a syntactically complete thought", then your fragment is obviously two sentences. So the question becomes: why do you even care? What difference does it make? Let's say I tell you you have three and a half sentences there. Now what?

Comment: (Not trying to be dismissive or inflammatory, by the way. Quite the opposite. It feels like you are withholding from us the *actual* question or problem that you are faced with. So please do elaborate.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yes, you are right, I just added my real problem to the question above. I expected to find out some "formal" rules or definitions for the usage of semicolon, but it looks it's not that case. I also think my problem is kinda odd now.

Comment: @JayWong Definitely a question for the professor, as a sentence will be defined logically, not grammatically.

Comment: Semicolons are a full stop mark. They have the same intonation curve as the period, and they go after a complete clause. Or sentence. Certainly that's common in writing, [as Lewis Thomas points out](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73944/15299), "The period tells you that that is that; if you didn't get all the meaning you wanted or expected, anyway you got all the writer intended to parcel out and now you have to move along. But with a semicolon there you get a pleasant little feeling of expectancy; there is more to come; to read on; it will get clearer."

Comment: Since linguists can't even agree on a definition of 'sentence', the question seems rather pointless. Ask your professor for their preference.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Semicolons are a full stop mark. They have the same intonation curve as the period, and they go after a complete clause. Or sentence. Certainly that's common in writing, [as Lewis Thomas points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73944/15299), "The period tells you that that is that; if you didn't get all the meaning you wanted or expected, anyway you got all the writer intended to parcel out and now you have to move along. But with a semicolon there you get a pleasant little feeling of expectancy; there is more to come; to read on; it will get clearer."